# Why doesn't ATT Samsung Galaxy S2 detect ICS update OTA and how to update?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, ota-update

My Samsung Galaxy S2 has the Android 2.3.6 version and a while ago I read that there would be an ICS update (http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/25/ics-att-samsung-galaxy-s-ii/). I have been checking for an update via OTA, but it keeps saying my software is up to date. What's wrong and how can I update it to ICS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the Ice Cream Sandwich update for the Galaxy S2 on AT&T was [never pushed over the air](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/07/09/att-galaxy-s-ii-skyrocket-ice-cream-sandwich-update-now-available/), but only via [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/).

In order to install the update you'll need to install and use Kies. If you do, I strongly recommend creating a system restore point (Windows) before installing it.